# Per-User Database connections to write SQL query and visualize

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, performance, activerecord, sequel

We are looking for advise as we are having an issue. We are enabling our users to add their own database connections and write SQL against it and visualize data (writing SQL and Visualize we support through features we enabled). This was an add-on functionality we created. Its possible that each user may add many connections (database) and write many many queries against it and visualize via dashboard.

To enable it, our contractor created a model to store all the database credentials (not .yml) and using to enable running the queries.

The issue is that even with very very few connections, we are getting an  error -""error":"connection to server at "127.0.0.1", port 5432 failed: FATAL:  sorry, too many clients already\nconnection to server at "127.0.0.1", port 5432 failed: FATAL:  sorry, too many clients already". The issue is that each query is creating a connection that are not being closed and so its failing very quickly.

Anyone deal with a similar problem and handling such dynamic database connections and executing SQL against it at scale? Any ideas of how to solve it?

How the System works

1. User/customer can add their external database credentials (postgreql, snowflake etc - we support 4-5 cloud database/DW). These credentials are stored in a model/table in postgresql
2. User can then write a query against it (SQL through an interface)
3. User can pick visualization and build dashboards (1 or more)

I have one table which name is user_db and in user_db table i am storing user own database credentials,

While a user open/refreshes page/dashboard ..say there are more then 20 charts (for e.g) on a dashboard.... which are dynamic, and currently it will open new connection for each charts and if user reload page 3 time then 20*3 means 60 open connection for a single user. Now if we multiply with each user and their own connections to various databases etc, it will be down in no time

The contractor was not using active record for this functionality so can not able to use active record function.

Comment: You need to provide much more details of how this system works. "It is possible that each user may add many connection...". Connections from where? Connection to where? To a database on the user's own computer? To an arbitary database on the internet? To your database? A flowchart would be very helpful.

Comment: @Casper Thanks for your comment. I am adding more details

Comment: @Casper Hope the above details help. Any advise is most appreciated

Comment: Ok. It helps, but there is one more detail "The issue is that each query is creating a connection that are not being closed and so its failing very quickly". Why is the connection not closed? Where is the error coming from? Is it coming from the client's own database? Who is telling you "too many connections"? The client's DB? And why is it "not being closed"?

Comment: client database ...gave this error, they explain to me this issue and provided me log which is mentioned above.

Comment: We also use this same approach actually to connect to our application database too as we allow customers to write their own queries against their data and create dashboard. So this error happens / comes from our app too for queries relating to our database. So both are are issues - client side (as explained in above comment) and ours

Comment: Even if we can solve client side....that would be good enough for now. We have alternatives probably for the other issue

Comment: I think this issue is too complex to solve through SO. There is still a lot of info missing in order to know what exactly your server is doing. Normally Rails uses connection pooling which prevents too many connections to the DB. But you say you had a "contractor" create something. That sounds like neither you, but especially anyone here at SO does not know what your contractor code is doing. Therefore quite hard to solve this problem. Basically you would need to post your full server code in order to figure out what is going on. SO is for simple focused problems, not such wide scope issues.

Comment: I suggest you ask your contractor, or hire one that can solve it :)